# How can I kill a Java program that is left hanging (in Windows )?

Tags: java, powershell, networking

Suppose that in Java I have a simple Echo Client/Server pair. I start up the Server process, but I never actually start the Client process.

What I'd like to do, is have a third program  (call it "Parent"), that will automatically kill this Server program after 30 seconds of being idle.

Could I use Powershell to do this? Or do I need to use C or other programming?

Comment: Isn't it easier to have the server program do this by itself?

Comment: basically you don't want to do stuff like that, you can create another thread in your server that will break the loop after n amounts of seconds and exit nicely

Comment: @Kenney - True, it is easier . However, in my case I want to need to have a  sort-of "Super Parent" , that would actually restart the Client-Server pair.  So  it's as if we're replacing the human who would notice the server died, and then manually restart the Client-Server   .  Admittedly , it's a contrived example (I realize it is not so practical either) , but it's part of academic  exercise.  Guessing, It would end up "hacky" for sure

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you have a good way to:
1) uniquely identify the server process
2) determine server is idle

If there will never be two (or more) instances of the server process, then you can identify the process by name (make sure your process has a unique name!)

Determining that the server is idle may be tricky (hence the comments to implement the server stopping itself without resorting to a "parent" process). However if the server is memory or CPU intensive when it is active you may be able to take advantage of that to distinguish idle from busy. You can use `get-process (gps)` to determine the process' current CPU and memory use. The trick will be to know how long it's been idle if it currently looks idle. To do this reliably you will need to poll with `gps` more frequently than it takes the server to process a request. Otherwise you may poll before the server is busy, then the server is busy, and then you poll again when it's idle. But you'll think it was idle the whole time.

You can avoid the dilemma above by having the server change something when it knows it has been idle for 30 seconds, like the window title. (But if you're doing that why not just have the server terminate itself?)

Once the PS script determines the server is idle then `get-process -name yourServerProcess|stop-process` will stop the server process. Specify "yourServerProcess" without the .EXE at the end. If you get a permissions error, then run PS as administrator.